# Display on Last Page of Export

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am attempting to follow the instructions on adding a header/footer to a kendo-ui grid here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#template-headers-and-footers

However, I only want the header and footer to be displayed on the last page of the PDF export and I'm not exactly sure how to toggle the visible property when it is the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by using the following in my kendo-template:

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="pdf-page-template">
    <div class="page-template">
        # if(pageNum === totalPages) {#
            <!-- custom header/footer -->
        #}#
    </div>
</script>
```